# Adobe Flex simple calculator

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

Hello everyone. I built a program in Flex Builder back in 2011. I have since lost the project files for it and I am trying to rebuild it. At one point, I knew how to do this, but for one reason or another, how I pulled it off now escapes me. It's really incredibly simple.

- textInput 1
- textInput 2
- textInput 3

dynamic label for result *x*

In my original, the user would input values into the three boxes, as the values were entered for each box the label would read "n/a", once the final value was input it automatically populated the label with the result of the math. In this particular case, it would be:

*x* = (input1/(60/input2))/input3

I am not a programmer, and there have been some changes since I accomplished this last. I've tried starting over from scratch, but I can't seem to get a working result. If someone could help crash me through this one calculation I can proceed again on my own, I just need a refresher. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I should note that my problem isn't with the math, but rather not remembering the syntax for the change events for the textInputs and the syntax for the variable calls. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like that may help you.

```
private function SomeMath():void
{
    dynamicTextBox.text = (input1.text/(60/input2.text))/input3.text;
}
```

and all these `dynamicTextBox`, `input1`, `input2`, and `input3` are the `id`s which are defined at correspoding part of `mxml` file.